# Keep track of specific errors in Google Cloud Error Logs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, error-handling, error-logging

I am using GCP with Cloud Run, SQL etc with a Node.js application. I have a specific type of error that appear quite often, related to a Twitter API call. Quite often I get this "Rate limit exceeded" error from the API which I handle like this:

```
items.forEach((item) => {
if (item.body.status == 429) {
            throw Error("Rate limit exceeded")
}
}).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

This appears in the logs but I would like it to be tracked in GCP Error list https://console.cloud.google.com/errors so I can see if my efforts to limit this specific error is going better. I don't want it to break the script so I also want to catch the error. How can I solve this best?

Comment: GCP Errors will automatically show errors from Cloud Run. No additional setup is required. Is that code writing text to stdout? or logging an error?

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs

Comment: Thanks. What I mean is that I am aware that everything shows up in the logs but the aggregated counts of each errors in the logs are shown on this page which makes it easy to see if a certain error is being solved. Checking the logs for certain errors by plain search does not give the same overview. I want to see if a certain error is less common today than yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce with your exact syntax (I'm not a nodejs expert) but I've been able to get errors reported in both Error Reporting and Logging via the following code:

```
try {
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.body.status == 429) {
      console.log(new Error("Rate limit exceeded"));
    }
  })
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Note that instead of throwing the error in the if block I just `console.log(new Error("Rate limit exceeded"))` and Error Reporting automatically picks it up.

The "Rate limit exceeded" does appear for me out of the box in the Error Reporting dashboard:
[image]

**and** in the logs:
[image]

Also note that the Logging page has an histogram view above the log entries that shows occurrences of the logs over time. By just filtering on the textPayload with the errors, you can view a detailed count of these errors over time in the histogram.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I do however need the error to be caught (so that a for loop doesn't break for example) and still be measured in some way. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you show how you populate the items list with the Http responses so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: I see. So the big difference here is that you removed the "throw"? Which console.log would it be here that actually writes the error in the log? I will test this and get back in a short while.

Comment: Tested now and Yes! This solved my issue. Great thanks, @LundinCast!